# Get a file from the same folder when importing (without hardcoding the path)

Tags: python, import

I'd like to know how I can access important_file.txt without hardcoding the path.
I run main.py that imports some code from myfile.py, where I need to read important_file.txt
Any ideas on how I can do this?

Files:

```
main.py
mydir/
    mydir2/
        myfile.py
        important_file.txt
```

main.py

```py
from mydir.mydir2.myfile import MyClass
MyClass.dostuff()
```

mydir/mydir2/myfile.py

```py
class MyClass:
    def dostuff():
        pass
        # something to read important_file.txt
        # without hardcoding it (writing mydir/mydir2/important_file.txt)
```

Command

```sh
python3 main.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__file__` to read the path of your module. Since `myfile.py` and `important_file.txt` are on the same directory you can then use `os.path.dirname` to get the name of the directory and join it with your file name to get an absolute path to your `.txt` file. In your `myfile.py` do:

```
import os


class MyClass:
    def dostuff():
        dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        with open(os.path.join(dirname, "important_file.txt")) as f:
            print(f.read())
```